# Extracción de determinados ficheros de una lista en Python

Tags: python

Tengo 1200 ficheros extensión `.txt` en un directorio con la siguiente nomenclatura:

```
T1A1, T1A2, T1A3........ T1A60
T2A1, T2A2, T2A3......... T2A60
.
.
. 
T10A1, T10A2, T10A3...... T10A60
```

Y lo mismo pero cambiando la letra A por la D

Es decir,

```
T1D1, T1D2, T1D3,...       T1D60
T2D1, T2D2, T2D3,...       T2D60
.
.
.
T10D1, T10D2, T10D3,...      T10D60
```

Por lo tanto `60 + 60 = 120 * 10 ( T) = 1200`

Tengo todos esos ficheros en una lista en python y quiero eliminar todos los que contengan la letra D y de los que tienen la letra A, solamente quiero hasta el 45.

¿Alguien tiene una idea?

Comment: ¿Para qué los tienes en una lista si puedes generar tú los nombres? En lugar de filtrar nombres, resulta más práctico crear una nueva lista: `[f"T{i}A{j}" for i in range(1,11) for j in range(1,46)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que 'a' es tu lista de archivos, asi se eliminan los archivos con D:

```
a = ["T1A1", "T1A2", "T1A3", "T1A60", "T2A1", "T2A2", "T2A3", "T2A60", "T10A1", "T10A2", "T10A3", "T10A60", "T1D1", "T1D2", "T1D3"]
lista_sin_D = [ x for x in a if "D" not in x ]
```

Y para el caso de los archivos de A menores de 45 debes usar expresiones regulares:

```
import re
lista_A_menor45 = [ x for x in a if int(re.match('.*?([0-9]+)$', x).group(1)) < 45 ]
```

Resultado final:

```
a = ['T1A1', 'T1A2', 'T1A3', 'T2A1', 'T2A2', 'T2A3', 'T10A1', 'T10A2', 'T10A3', 'T1D1', 'T1D2', 'T1D3']
```

Tambien puedes evaluar todo a la vez y asi recorrer la lista solo una vez, ahorrando tiempo de ejecucion:

```
lista_limpia = [ x for x in a if ("D" not in x) & (int(re.match('.*?([0-9]+)$', x).group(1)) < 45)]
```

Comment: La primera parte está perfecto pero la expresión regular me da un error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Ese error da cuando la expresion regular no encuentra nada, puedes compartime esa parte? asegurate de tener la importacion de la libreria 're'

Comment: import os

os.chdir("./envolventes")


diractual = os.getcwd()

ficheros = os.listdir(diractual)

lista_sin_D = [ x for x in ficheros if "D" not in x ]

import re
lista_A_menor45 = [ x for x in ficheros if int(re.match('.*?([0-9]+)$', x).group(1)) < 45 ]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Puede ser porque esté trabajando en utf-8??

Comment: Intentalo por partes, usa en una consola el `import re` y `re.match('.*?([0-9]+)$', "T2A60").group(1)` puede que el tipo del objeto sobre el que se busca la expresion regular no sea texto y necesites un str(x)

Comment: Haciéndolo en la consola sí me funciona

Comment: tal vez la x, es decir cada elemento de la lista, no sea un string. Comprueba el `type(x)`

Comment: Es tipo str....

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar los nombres de los ficheros usando solo una expresión regular, lo único complejo es crear el patrón necesario para validar los rangos 1-10 y 1-45:

```
'^T([1-9]|10)A([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5])\.txt$')
```

Veamos el patrón por partes:

- **^** --> Coincide con el inicio de la cadena.
- **T** --> Coincide con el carácter "T".
- **([1-9]|10)** --> Grupo que valida caracteres en el rango "1" a "9" ó (`|`) la cadena "10".
- **A** --> Coincide con el carácter "A".
- **([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5])** --> Este grupo se encarga de validar los números en el rango 1-45 (ambos incluidos). Puede ser un carácter entre "1" y "9" (números entre 1 y 9) ó un carácter entre "1" y "3" seguido de otro carácter entre "0" y "9" (números entre 10 y 39) ó un "4" seguido de un carácter entre "0" y "5" (números entre 40 y 45).
- **.txt** --> Coincide con la cadena ".txt", `.` es un carácter especial por lo que hay que escaparlo.
- **$** --> Coincide con el final de la cadena.

---

```
import re

ficheros = ["T1A10.txt", "T11A42.txt", "T2D21.txt",
            "T5A48.txt", "T7A45.txt",  "T8A9.png" ]

patt = re.compile(r'^T([1-9]|10)A([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5])\.txt$')
res = [fichero for fichero in ficheros if re.match(patt, fichero)]
```

Para el ejemplo anterior la salida es:

```
>>> res
['T1A10.txt', 'T7A45.txt']
```